# Issues making or receiving calls and texts with a LG P500 (Software Version V20e)?

Tags: sms, calls, connection-issues, 3g, lg-optimus-one

I just got a LG P-500 device and I want to deploy with it. Everything is working fine, except that I cant make phone calls, receive phone calls, send SMS or receive SMS.

The phone is on its stock ROM (Android 2.3.3, Software Version V20e). The Mobile Company is Orange. The phone recognizes the mobile company, and even shows the signal bar as full, but when I'm trying to call I'm being directed straight to "Call Ended" screen, and when I send SMS, I receive back a "SMS wasn't sent" notification. The SIM is Working on my SGS.

I tried everything, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you set up APNs for Orange?  (Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names).

Comment: Yes, Still doesnt work..

Comment: @MatthewRead you need APNs to *make a call*? I thought they were for data only ("mobile networks", not cell service)?

Comment: Is it possible that the phone's Stock ROM is for 850MHZ sim cards? because in my country there is a Mobile Company that uses 850MHZ instead of 900MHZ and the phone is from her.

Comment: @LStyle The network frequencies that can be used are determined by the hardware of the phone.  [GSMArena says](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_one_p500-3516.php) `2G Network GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900; 3G Network HSDPA 900 / 2100` so you should be OK for 2G at least.

Comment: @Izzy The mobile voice network is a mobile network :P but I was focusing on SMS not working.

Comment: @MatthewRead still strange, but other countries might do things different. I cannot remember having to set this up when I didn't want "mobile data". And I remember hearing from people they could do calls fine but not go to the net (no APN defined). So this is new for me, that an APN is required to make calls and send SMS (MMS is something different, and needs an APN).

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, on my network I can only receive calls without the APNs set up, not make them or send/receive SMSes.

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks for these details! Everyday something new to learn...

Comment: I still cant recieve calls, SMS or make calls and send SMS..
If I'll flash a new Custom ROM and root the phone will it work?

Comment: In India, I am using LgP500. APNs are not required for voice calls and plain text SMS and is definitely needed for MMS. The messaging app in this phone decides the format based on its contents. @LStyle, just as a test, can you swap another working SIM on your LgP500 and run tests on both phones?

Comment: Also, when you swap the SIM, note the message centre number, which is a mobile number to which all your text SMS are forwarded. This will be set automatically to operator's number in message settings when SIM is inserted. A valid message centre number is required for a successful SMS use. If still problems exist, I would suspect a faulty app or ROM.

Comment: I am trying to root the device, but I have one question:
after the SuperOneClick Procedure is done I read that I need to reboot my phone - but how can I do it? should I power it OFF and then Turn it ON? I cant reboot it other way..